# Copiar el valor de un input dinamico a otro input dinamico

Tags: php, javascript

Hola soy nueva en javascript, pero estoy trabajando en un input dinámico que se multiplican pero como podria hacer que el primer dato del input dinámico se copie en el los demás inputs... Muchas gracias

Aquí esta una parte de mi código

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
          var i = 0;
          $(".origenDato").keyup(function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.destinoDato').val($(this).val());
          });

          $('#CantidadTeo-' + i).change(function() {
            upd_art(i)
          });
          $('#CantidadFab-' + i).change(function() {
            upd_art(i)
          });
          $('#add').click(function() {
            i++;
          });
    });
```

Comment: Si tus inputs tienen la misma clase, y creas la función `$(claseDinamica).on('keyup',function(){});` esta se propagará a cada elemento que contenga dicha clase, no es necesario repetir código  Ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/LancxzL7/

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podría hacer es iterar por cada elemento que tenga la clase `.destinoDato` y pasarle el valor que obtuvo el evento keyup de esta manera:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){ 
      var i=0; 
      $(".origenDato").keyup(function () { 

        let valor_a_pasar=$(this).val();
        $('.destinoDato').each(function(){
          $(this).val(valor_a_pasar);
        });

      });

      $('#CantidadTeo-' + i).change(function(){
        upd_art(i)
      });

      $('#CantidadFab-'+ i).change(function(){
        upd_art(i)
      });

      $('#add').click(function(){  
        i++;  
      });
    });
```